# QTranslator cannot seem to find my .ls file even though I am certain the specified path is correct

Tags: c++, qt, translation

It seems very basic in the tutorials, simply specify the path of the .st or .qm to the translator `.load` function and then install it in your app. Whenever I try to do this, the load function returns `false` and can never seem to load my file properly.

I have verified that it is exactly where the path leads. I even read that sometimes it goes up one folder for some reason and put a copy of my file there. I have tried leaving the file in the same folder as the executable, exactly where `QApplication::applicationDirPath()` leads. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The following code is what I am having a problem with, it is in the `main` function of the `main.cpp` file.

```
QApplication application(argc, argv); 

QString path = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
path.append("/translations/");
QTranslator translator;
bool loaded = translator.load("assistant_fr.ts", path);
if (loaded)
    application.installTranslator(&translator);

MainWindow main_window(application.applicationDisplayName());

main_window.show();
return application.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it worked with a .qm file.